# Make ng-http-loader run with SystemJs

Tags: systemjs

I want to add the ng-http-loader library to my Angular5 project, but I do not know how to get it running with SystemJS. I know I have to add something to the systemjs.config, but I tried to target several files inside the node_modules/ng-http-loader/ directory or the directory itself, but I always get the error, that he can't find the module.

```
  Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/ng-http-loader/ng-http-loader.module
    wrapFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1166:30
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:17
    Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:28
    ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:499:24
    invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:9
    globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1566:17

    Error loading http://localhost:3000/ng-http-loader/ng-http-loader.module as "ng-http-loader/ng-http-loader.module" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
    Stack trace:
    (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/ng-http-loader/ng-http-loader.module
    wrapFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1166:30
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:17
    Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:28
    ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:499:24
    invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:9
    globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1566:17

    Error loading http://localhost:3000/ng-http-loader/ng-http-loader.module as "ng-http-loader/ng-http-loader.module" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
```

I also asked the author, but he is not experienced with systemjs and therefore was not able to help me. Does anybody else know which file I should target?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Having never used ng-http-loader, try this as a starting point:

```
System.config({
    "paths": {
        "npm:": "node_modules/"
    },
    "map": {
        "ng-http-loader": "npm:ng-http-loader"
    },
    "packages": {
        "ng-http-loader": {
          "main": "ng-http-loader.module.js",
          "defaultExtension": "js"
        }
    }
```

It's possible that other mappings are required in addition to the above e.g. to the components folder etc.